# Returning a struct containing mutable values

Tags: rust

I have the following code, where I'm trying to return the struct `Foo` with a set of default values for the field `values`. These values may be changed later. But the compiler complains:

```
error: `initial` does not live long enough
```

How this could be achieved? Any alternatives?

```rust
struct Foo <'a> {
    values: &'a mut Vec<i32>,
}

impl <'a> Foo <'a> {
    fn new() -> Foo <'a> {
        let initial = vec![1, 2];

        Foo { values: &mut initial }
    }
}

let my_foo = Foo::new();

my_foo.values.push(3);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first is that you don't need to use `&mut` to make a structure field mutable.  Mutability is *inherited* in Rust.  That is, if you have a `Foo` stored in a mutable variable (`let mut f: Foo`), its fields are mutable; if it's in an immutable variable (`let f: Foo`), its fields are immutable.  The solution is to just use:

```rust
struct Foo {
    values: Vec<i32>,
}
```

and return a `Foo` by value.

The second problem (and the source of the actual compilation error) is that you're trying to return a borrow to something you created in the function.  This is *impossible*.  No, there is no way around it; you can't somehow extend the lifetime of `initial`, returning `initial` as well as the borrow won't work.  Really.  This is one of the things Rust was specifically designed to absolutely forbid.

If you want to transfer something *out* of a function, one of two things must be true:

1. It is being stored somewhere outside the function that will outlive the current call (as in, you were *given* a borrow as an argument; returning doesn't count), or
2. You are returning *ownership*, not just a borrowed reference.

The corrected `Foo` works because it *owns* the `Vec<i32>`.