# Do a container's members inherit its mutability?

Tags: rust

Something like this compiles and runs fine:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Member {
    x: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec![Member { x: 5 }; 5];

    arr[0].x = 25;

    println!("{}", arr[0].x); // Gives 25
}
```

Is it because if a reference to a container such as `Vec` is made mutable, then its elements "inherit" its mutability?

Comment: `Vec`'s implementation of `IndexMut` takes `&mut Vec<T>`  and returns an `&mut T`.

Comment: Consider `BTreeSet` and `HashSet` -- they have members that are always immutable. `Arena` (from the [typed-arena](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/1.3.0/typed_arena/index.html) crate) is a data structure that hands out `&mut` references to elements but only requires a `&Arena` to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, mutability is "inherited" by the fields of a type depending on the binding of the variable. From *The Rust Programming Language*'s [chapter on defining structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch05-01-defining-structs.html):

> If the instance is mutable, we can change a value by using the dot
>   notation and assigning into a particular field
>
> [...]
>
> Note that the entire instance must be mutable

However, that's not what's happening here. As [Veedrac points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915905/do-container-members-inherit-its-mutability#comment82800146_47915905), you aren't accessing the fields of the container, but you are calling a method.

The `[]` operator is powered by the [`IndexMut` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html):

```
pub trait IndexMut<Idx>: Index<Idx>
where
    Idx: ?Sized,
{
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: Idx) -> &mut Self::Output;
}
```

Your code translates to something akin to:

```
{
    let tmp: &mut Member = IndexMut::index_mut(&mut arr, 0);
    tmp.x = 25;
}
```

In this case, nothing is "inherited", it's explicitly granted via the method implementations.

See also:

- [Returning a struct containing mutable values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29598264/155423)